# Negative peak clamping circuit

Tags: capacitor, diode-clamp

[image]

The picture shows a clamper that clamps the negative voltage peak of a signal to -5 volts. I have two questions:

1- What is the function of the 15 volts battery ? It says that diode does not turn on without it but I don't understand why?

2- Also the book says for zero input voltage the output is -5V which is the summation of Zener diode voltage and diode. But clearly in figure (b) -5 corresponds to negative max voltage, and not zero input.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it helps me to redraw circuits in a manner which shows higher potentials at the top, and lower potentials at the bottom. Perhaps it can help you too, so I'll do that here.

For figure (b) they are referring to the circuit as drawn, but in figure (c) the phrase "R returned directly to ground" leads me to think that they mean "remove the battery and replace with a direct short to ground".

Here's how those two configurations would look, drawn in a way that makes more sense to my mind:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKtl2f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, D2 is forward biased, and drops 0.6V, and D1 is reverse biased, dropping a further 4.4V, for a total of 5V. This places the output (in the absence of any input) at –5V with respect to ground.

Importantly, that voltage at "OUT" can rise easily, if the input drives it so, but it cannot drop below –5V, because it is clamped at that minimum by the diodes. This means that the *lowest* point in the input signal will be "mapped", shifted to –5V, the rest of the waveform sitting atop that "base".

On the right we have no EMF to forward or reverse bias either diode. If the output voltage rises above zero, D2 is reverse biased, and neither diode can influence the output. However, those diodes *will* prevent the output from dropping under –5V.

Unless the input signal has sufficient amplitude to cause that clamping to occur, resistor R simply biases the output at ground level, 0V.